# File copying get slower along with time

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am trying to copy large data from one partition to other partition on windows 7 (around 50 GB of data), copying start fast and it shows around 10-13 MB/s in start but as time pass it slows down and reaches just till 1 MB/s.

How i can improve it? Kindly suggest ways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "probably" because Windows will cache the file you're copying into RAM and so initially, the transfer rates are quite fast. But this speed degrades over time. 
1 MB/s does sound real slow, and to improve it you could use a faster port eg.USB3 or a newer and better USB drive.(I'm making this assumption that you're copying to a pen drive or something, as an HDD generally provides really high speeds). I got a new pen drive and it gives me 6 MB/s with USB2. So you can see the difference it makes.

Edit:
If that's the case, don't copy to the same drive. Such a problem can only be solved if you copy to a different drive.

Here's an explanation of why:

See, if you're copying to the same drive, the read/write head needs to first copy from one part of the drive, then reposition, then write. And it takes time to reposition, and that's the reason it is slow.

Comment: I am trying to copy data between different partition on same had disk, the data is around 50 GB...

Comment: @user253129's answer is correct once the cache is filled your speeds will degrad. Solution is to buy a faster drive like a ssd or to short stroke your hdd